# How to get property value coming from structure

Tags: linux, common-lisp

I have trouble with Common Lisp under Linux Mint 17.3.
The problem is, that I could not get the "wort" item within the structure definition.
I try too "loop" to get the it, but i fail.

```
(defstruct deutschesFrageWort wort pro1 pro2)
(setq  deFrageWort-1 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort "liebst" :pro1 'du :pro2 'sie))
(defvar deFrageWort-2 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'liebst :pro1 'du :pro2 'ihn))
(defvar deFrageWort-3 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'magst  :pro1 'du :pro2 'ihn))
(defvar deFrageWort-4 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'magst  :pro1 'du :pro2 'sie))
;;
(setq deFrageWoerterCollection '(
      deFrageWort-1
      deFrageWort-2
      deFrageWort-3
      deFrageWort-4
))


(loop :for currentFrageWort :in deFrageWoerterCollection
      :do (progn
          (format t "~A~" symstr)
          (eval  defragewort-1-wort)
      )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put symbols in `deFrageWoerterCollection`. Put the structures themselves.

You need to call `deutschesFrageWort-wort` to get the `wort` slot out of the structure.

```
(setq deFrageWoerterCollection (list deFrageWort-1 deFrageWort-2 deFrageWort-3 deFrageWort-4)

(loop :for currentFrageWort :in deFrageWoerterCollection
      :do (format t "~A~&" (deutschesFrageWort-wort currentFrageWort)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find a correction of the formatting. I also included slight modifications so that your example would evaluate. I included Barmar's answer so as to make your code do what you want. It seems minor but providing correctly formatted code helps readability immensely.

```
(defstruct deutschesFrageWort wort pro1 pro2)
(defvar deFrageWort-1 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'liebst :pro1 'du :pro2 'sie))
(defvar deFrageWort-2 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'liebst :pro1 'du :pro2 'ihn))
(defvar deFrageWort-3 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'magst  :pro1 'du :pro2 'ihn))
(defvar deFrageWort-4 (make-deutschesFrageWort :wort 'magst  :pro1 'du :pro2 'sie))

(defvar deFrageWoerterCollection
  (list deFrageWort-1
        deFrageWort-2
        deFrageWort-3
        deFrageWort-4))
(loop :for currentFrageWort :in deFrageWoerterCollection
      :do (format t "~A~&" (deutschesFrageWort-wort currentFrageWort)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the symbol value:

```
CL-USER 1 > (loop for currentFrageWort in deFrageWoerterCollection
                  do (format t "~A " (deutschesFrageWort-wort
                                       (symbol-value currentFrageWort))))
liebst LIEBST MAGST MAGST 
NIL
```